# git unable to fetch upstream, claims repository doesn't exist

Tags: git

I'm having trouble updating my fork from the master. When I type git fetch upstream I get the error:

```
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm using ssh to access the repo, and it recognises that the repo exists in other instances.

Comment: What is output of `git remote`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I fixed this with git rm upstream and then adding it in again. Which makes no sense whatsoever, but hey.

Comment: It probably means that the url or the remote name had a typo.